# Batch file : Encrypted opt out repeats it self for every file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Hi and thanks for answer, so my batch file that is intended to encrypt certain files with certain extensions. So there is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Alphabet=0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set "lowCase=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
:a offset "input string" outVar=
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "inString=%~2"
set maxLen=80
set offset=11
set fname=%random%.%random%.%random%.%random%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
    for /f "tokens=*" %%X in ('dir /b /s *.encodeme') do (
        FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /v /L /i /b /c:"INDEX?" "%%X"') DO (
            SET "line=%%a"
            call :A %offset% "!line!" a=
            echo !a!
            type %fname% > %%X
            del /Q %fname%
        )
    )
)>"%fname%"
 
:A offset "input string" outVar=
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
set "inString=%~2"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /L %%i in (0,1,61) do (
    set /A "i=(%%i + %1) %% 62"
    set c["!Alphabet:~%%i,1!"]=!i!
)
set "outVar="
for /L %%i in (0,1,%maxLen%) do (
   set "char=!inString:~%%i,1!"
   if defined char (
      for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!char!") do (
         if defined c["%%c"] (
            set j=!c["%%c"]!
            if "!lowCase:%%c=%%c!" neq "%lowCase%" set /A "j-=26"
            for /F %%j in ("!j!") do set "outVar=!outVar!!Alphabet:~%%j,1!"
         ) else (
            set "outVar=!outVar!!char!"
         )
      )
   )
)

( 
endlocal 
for /F "delims=" %%a in ("%outVar:!=^!%") do endlocal & set "%3=%%a"
)
```

I have problem with the script that it will repeat its previous encrypted results.

For example, first encrypted file content is ok : `Er6HGFJFrq6FJpFr6`

Second example file content is repeated from previous on :

```
Er6HGFJFrq6FJpFr6
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\16383.29528.16703.12516
n6GJp6GJp7GF6
```

I want it to be just :

```
n6GJp6GJp7GF6
```

Sorry for my English, if you could help me, thank you!

Comment: Batch is usually case-insensitive (there are well-documented exceptions) so the label `:a` at line 5 is identical to the label `:A` at the start of the second block of code (after `for...%%X...`) At a guess, I'd expect that the `call :A` in the `for %%X` loop will attempt to execute from the first `:a`. Also, batch does not have `sections`, `procedures`, `functions` or other such structures. Once the `for...%%X` loop is finished, batch will simply proceed through the label `:A` and execute the `for..%%i` commands. A`goto :eof` would skip to end-of-file (colon required)

Comment: @Magoo, `call` or `goto` scans the batch file for the given label from the current position to the end, then from top to the current position…